# Running a python script with apache gives permission error

Tags: python, apache

I have been trying to write to a file using a python script which will be executed by apache. And this is the script that I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Cache-Control: no-store"
print "Pragma: no-cache"
print "Expires: 0"
print

file_name = '/my/path/file.ext'
try:
    open(file_name, 'w').write('hello')
    print "Good"
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

When I run the script through the command-line, the result is: `Good`, however when apache runs the script, I get `I/O error(13): Permission denied`

A couple notes:

- The directory it is trying to write is writable (+w)
- The file is in an *executable* directory (+x) and all its parent directories are also executable
- I have been running the script through the command line with the same user as apache (and it is working).

Comment: Don't even bother with CGI. if you have a database use django. if you don't use Flask.

Comment: @e4c5 This is part of a bigger project, switching to flask (or django) is out of the question.

Comment: ok, but grappling with CGI like this reminds me of how we did things 20 years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this particular instance was SELinux which was blocking the operation. I temporarily disabled SELinux, but the better-answer is to add a security policy for this operation.